# android remove known line from txt file

Tags: java, android

I need to remove one line from txt file and I already know the position of this line. 
I know how to replace data on txt file reading whole content but I would like to delete line from specific position. Thank you.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/data/"+ PACKAGE_NAME +"/myFile.txt"));

//delete Line on position 2 (as example)


br.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read all of the lines from the `File` first and store them in a `List<String>`. Then you could remove the index and write back all of the lines. Perhaps it might look something like:

```
public void removeLine(final File file, final int lineIndex) throws IOException{
    final List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
    final Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
    while(reader.hasNextLine())
        lines.add(reader.nextLine());
    reader.close();
    assert lineIndex >= 0 && lineIndex <= lines.size() - 1;
    lines.remove(lineIndex);
    final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));
    for(final String line : lines)
        writer.write(line);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    final File file = ...;
    removeLine(file, 2);
}
```

The code above will remove the 3rd line.

Answer (score -2):

by jni, use

1. `open`
2. `mmap`
3. `memcpy`
4. `munmap`
5. `ftruncate`
6. `close`

Comment: insane explanation, gotta try this